# How to get Effect Size from tt_ind_solve_power?

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, scipy.stats

I am trying to get the Effect Size given my alpha, power, sample size, ratio. I found tt_ind_solve_power to do this but how would this work for 4 variants + 1 control?

This is how I have it currently

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import tt_ind_solve_power

effect_size = tt_ind_solve_power(nobs1=X,
                                 alpha=0.05, 
                                 power=0.8, 
                                 ratio=1, 
                                 alternative='two-sided')
```

My goal is to get the effect size for my experiment with 4 variants. How do I define my nobs=X parameter in the function above? And would the outcome be the effect size per variant or in aggregate?

```
Sample Sizes:
    Variant 1: 990
    Variant 2: 1001
    Variant 3: 1100
    Variant 4: 999
    Control:  1002
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What hypothesis test do you want to use?  t-test is for one or two sample tests. With 5 samples we can use either t-test on pairs of samples or anova or wald tests on joint hypothesis.

Comment: @Josef I think t-test on pairs works. but i am open whatever works with that effect size calculator. Do you have any idea how to tweak the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, we need sample size for the treatment, `nobs1`, and  `ratio` for the power effectsize computation.

`ratio` is defined by `nobs2 = nobs1 * ratio`, so `ratio = nobs2 / nobs1` where `nobs2` is the number of observations of the control or reference treatment.

For comparing variant1 with the control use:

```
nobs1 = 990
ratio = 1002 / nobs1
```

and similar for nobs1 of the other variants or treatments.